# How do I delete a book off of my Kindle account?

Tags: kindle, amazon

I've noticed that once you buy a book on a kindle account, it's there forever!  You can't shake it.  How do I get rid of a book on a kindle account?

Comment: "There's no fresh start in today's world. Any twelve-year-old with a cell phone could find out what you did. Everything we do is collated and quantified. Everything sticks." - Selena Kyle, "Dark Knight Rising"

Comment: Dude I didn't do anything.  It was a book called `The Art of the Approach`.  Now that I'm married it's just not really appropriate to have anymore.  There's nothing dirty about it.

Comment: my edit comment was somewhat humorous. The real reason to remove was that the extra sentence didn't add any useful information to the question for either answerers or future readers.

Comment: Please accept [my answer](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/520/330) if it adequately addresses your question. :)

Comment: @MyPetOcean Please be patient I haven't gotten the chance to try it out yet.

Comment: Thanks, just a lot of abandoned questions laying around... haha.

Comment: Yep. ;D Abandoned question, haha.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to ['Manage Your Content and Devices'](http://www.amazon.com/manageyourkindle) on Amazon.
2. In the 'Your Content' section on that page, locate the row for the book you wish to delete.
3. In that the row, locate and click on the Actions button.
4. Select the 'Delete' option.

*NOTE: Though your Kindle Library will list Audible audiobooks, as well as Kindle ebooks, you cannot use this method to delete Audible audiobooks from your Library. Audible currently does not provide users this option. If you insist, you can contact Audible customer support and they will do it for you, or if the book is eligible for refund, you can initiate a so-called 'book return' (and receive a refund) on [the Account Details page](https://www.audible.com/account-details) of Audible.com, where you will see an 'eligible' link in the 'Return' column of the row corresponding to the audiobook you wish to return to Audible.*

Comment: Folloup question: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/523/does-deleting-a-book-from-a-kindle-account-delete-it-from-kindle-devices

Comment: Amazon's web interface offers no way to delete multiple books (I get a newspaper delivered daily, so I have hundreds of entries). I did find a script at http://pepa.info/check-and-delete/ which checks all the checkboxes and adds a "Bulk Delete" button, but so far it has not worked for me (in Chrome; perhaps it works in other browsers).

Comment: @PeterFlynn, Amazon has resolved your problem. As it stands now, Amazon leaves it to you to check each of the books you want to commit an Action on (i.e., there is no "Select All" button), but once you have checked all the books you want to delete, you can now select the orange "Delete" button at the top of the list.