# Does deleting a book from a Kindle account delete it from Kindle devices?

Tags: kindle, amazon, ebook-management, kindle-cloud-reader

This answer: [How do I delete a book off of my Kindle account?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-do-i-delete-a-book-off-of-my-kindle-account/520#520)  - shows that you can delete a book from your account/library on Amazon's web page.

What effect does this have on your Kindle readers?

1. Does it delete the book from the book list on Kindle devices?
2. Does it delete the book from the book files stored on Kindle devices (independently of #1)?
3. Do #1/#2 affect Kindle applications on various non-Kindle-device platforms as well?

Comment: I believe the answers to all of those is yes, but there's a simple way to test: just add a free Kindle book, load it onto one or more Kindle devices/apps, then remove the book off your libbrary, and see what happens.

Comment: that's only if it's `DRM` protected. if note it will just be removed from the `cloud`(librery). i don't know about 3.

Answer (score 4):

By deleting an ebook I assume that it is a matter of a book that you have purchased and finished reading. In this case if you delete your book from the online library all Kindle synced devices that had the book will also delete it.

In case you are talking about a book that you have published, and then unpublished for editing, the previous version of the book that was published and bought by a reader will continue to survive on their Kindle devices. When you finish editing and upload the changes the new version of the book will then be synced to the kindle devices.

Comment: 1984 ...  great. And they dare call that book. Books are supposed to preserve their content. The Kindle is an oxymoron.

Comment: @babou LOL, I thought you were referencing the book 1984 and saying it's not a book.  haha.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following:

1. Go to "Manage Your Content and Devices"
2. Delete a document (NB: not a book bought from the Kindle store)
3. On my Kindle (Paperwhite) go to "Sync and check for items"

The document still shows on the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the book will be deleted as soon as your Kindle syncs.
2. Yes, there won't be any trace of the book.
3. Yes, the same applies with Kindle For Android and PC. Amazon removes your content license the second you're connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not happen. I just tried the above and the book remains on my kindle paperwhite and opens normally for reading. I tried re synching but the book does not disappear off the device.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to clarify *what* does not happen. This answer is currently a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When I delete a book from "Manage Your Content and Devices" it will automatically sync and be removed from my non-Kindle device (e.g. Android tablet with Kindle app) but it does NOT automatically delete the book file from my Kindle 7th Gen. device, even after Sync-ing the device. I'm not sure if it removes the book title from the All books list of "My Library" on the Kindle device.

Answer (score 0):

The question and answers are vague and confusing and need editing.

My two cents, if only to add to the confusion:

Use `amazon.com/myk` to **manage** content.  To read material use `read.amazon.com`, or an app, or a Kindle device.

When you manage content these are the options I see for actions:

```
Deliver to  Default Device  (or)  Others
Delete
Clear furthest page read
Read Now
Add to collections
```

You should be able to delete **from** a device.  The option should be to delete local copy only, or delete local and cloud.

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me as well

if you delete a book from my kindle, then it's not deleted from the device, you need to do that manually as well, it's kinda OK but can be time consuming, after all it's so quick and easy to browse on the My Kidle Amazon page with a computer.

so i can totally agree with the poster, it does NOT delete it.